# Why the manual raised Transient Error exceptions are handled as an AggregateException?

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, azureservicebus

When I try to raise transient exception manually, it is always handled as `AggregateException`. Since it is handled as `AggregateException`  , it is not handled as transient error in my retry policy and not retried for the predefined retry count.

Transient errors are shown [here](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/A122E27E/192B1DF7) . 
Therefore I have tried `CommunicationException` and  `ServerErrorException` but it is handled as an AggregateException.

When I look for AggregateException, it says "Represents one or more errors that occur during application execution."  Yeah, it is so helpful!!!

Here is the example code of my case:

I have a retry policy which uses ServiceBusTransientErrorDetectionStrategy

```
public void TestManually()
{
    var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<ServiceBusTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(RetryStrategy.DefaultFixed);

    retryPolicy.Retrying += (obj, eventArgs) =>
        {
           Trace.TraceError("Hey!! I'm Retrying, CurrentRetryCount = {0} , Exception = {1}", eventArgs.CurrentRetryCount, eventArgs.LastException.Message);
        };


    retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() =>
        MyTestFunction().ContinueWith(t =>
        {    
            if (t.Exception != null) 
            {
                // A non-transient exception occurred or retry limit has been reached
               Trace.TraceError("This was not a transient exxception... It was: " + t.Exception.GetType().ToString());
            } 
        })); 

}


public Task MyTestFunction()
{  
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RaiseTransientErrorManually());
    return task; 
}


public void RaiseTransientErrorManually()
{
    //throw new CommunicationException(); 
    throw new ServerErrorException();
}
```

Let's say I call my function like this:

```
TestManually();
```

I'm very confused why the manually thrown exception (which is defined as Transient Error) is handled as AggregateException ? What I'm missing there?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question would be a *lot* more readable if you'd format your code more conventionally.

Comment: Please feel free to edit, or explain what you are actually looking for? I would love to make it more readable, Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Look at the indentation of `RaiseTransientErrorManually`, for example. Is that how it looks to you in Visual Studio? I'd be very surprised.

Comment: @JonSkeet, hoping it looks better now

Comment: Better - although now *everything* is indented by more than it needs to be. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions within asynchronous code are a tricky subject for two reasons.

1. The manner in which exceptions are handled (e.g. by `catch` blocks) is not always intuitive, and may seem inconsistent.
2. The manner in which libraries *document* the behavior for exceptions thrown by asynchronous methods is not always obvious.

I'll address each of these items below.

**Important Note:** This answer uses the term *asynchronous method* to refer to any method with a return type of `Task` or `Task<T>`. Languages with built-in support for asynchronous programming have their own related terminology which may differ in meaning.

### Exceptions Thrown by Asynchronous Methods

Asynchronous methods are capable of throwing exceptions before creating a `Task` or during the asynchronous execution of the task itself. While projects are not always consistent in the way exceptions are documented for asynchronous code, I like to include the following note with my projects to make things clear for my users.

*Note: only assume the following quote is true for a library which explicitly states it. The statement is specifically meant to address the second problem area described above.*

> The documentation for asynchronous methods does not distinguish between these two cases, allowing for any of the specified exceptions to be thrown in either manner.

#### Exceptions Prior to `Task` Creation

Exceptions thrown prior to the creation of the `Task` object representing the asynchronous operation must be caught directly by the calling code. For example, if the code throws an `ArgumentNullException` in this manner, the calling code would need to contain an exception handler for `ArgumentNullException` or `ArgumentException` to handle the exception.

Example code which throws a direct exception:

```
public Task SomeOperationAsync()
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Directly thrown.");
}
```

Example code which handles a directly-thrown exception:

```
try
{
    Task myTask = SomeOperationAsync();
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    // ex was thrown directly by SomeOperationAsync. This cannot occur if
    // SomeOperationAsync is an async function (§10.15 - C# Language Specification
    // Version 5.0).
}
```

#### Exceptions During Task Execution

Exceptions thrown during the asynchronous execution of the task are wrapped in an `AggregateException` object and returned by the `Exception` property. Exceptions thrown in this manner must be handled either by a task continuation that checks the `Exception` property, or by calling `Wait` or checking the `Result` property within an exception handling block that includes a handler for `AggregateException`.

In libraries that I create, I provide an additional guarantee for users which reads as follows:

*Note: only assume the following quote is true for a library which explicitly states it.*

> This library additionally ensures that exceptions thrown by asynchronous operations are not wrapped in multiple layers of `AggregateException`. In other words, an `ArgumentException` thrown during the asynchronous execution of a task will result in the `Exception` property returning an `AggregateException`, and that exception will not contain any nested instances of `AggregateException` in the `InnerExceptions` collection. In most cases, the `AggregateException` wraps exactly one inner exception, which is the original `ArgumentException`. This guarantee simplifies the use of the API is languages that support **async**/**await**, since those operators automatically unwrap the first layer of `AggregateException`.

Example methods which each throw an exception during task execution:

```
public Task SomeOperationAsync()
{
    return Task.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Directly thrown.");
        });
}

public async Task SomeOtherOperationAsync()
{
    throw new ArgumentException("async functions never throw exceptions directly.");
}
```

Example code which handles an exception during task execution:

```
try
{
    Task myTask = SomeOperationAsync();
    myTask.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException wrapperEx)
{
    ArgumentException ex = wrapperEx.InnerException as ArgumentException;
    if (ex == null)
        throw;

    // ex was thrown during the asynchronous portion of SomeOperationAsync. This is
    // always the case if SomeOperationAsync is an async function (§10.15 - C#
    // Language Specification Version 5.0).
}
```

#### Consistent Exception Handling

Applications implementing specialized handling for exception which occur during asynchronous calls have multiple options available for consistent handling. The simplest solution, when available, involves using **async**/**await**. These operators automatically unwrap the first exception instance in the `InnerExceptions` collection of an `AggregateException`, resulting in behavior that appears to calling code as though the exception was directly thrown by the invoked method. The second method involves treating the original call as a continuation of another task, ensuring that all exceptions are presented as an `AggregateException` to the exception handling code. The following code shows the application of this strategy to an existing asynchronous call. Note that the `CompletedTask` class and `Then()` extension method are part of the separate [Rackspace Threading Library](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-threading) (open-source, Apache 2.0).

```
// original asynchronous method invocation
Task task1 = SomeOperationAsync();

// method invocation treated as a continuation
Task task2 = CompletedTask.Default.Then(_ => SomeOperationAsync());
```

Code using the continuation strategy for consistent error handling may benefit from the use of the `Catch()` methods, which are also part of the Rackspace Threading Library. This extension method behaves in a manner similar to **await**, automatically unwrapping the first exception instance in the `InnerExceptions` collection of an `AggregateException` before invoking the continuation function which handles the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As of Transient Fault Handling v6.0.1304.0 , the following code successfully retries as per the configured detection strategy:

Strategy:

```
public class SimpleHandlerStartegy : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
    {
        public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is WebException)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Code That Throws WebException:

```
async Task<int> SomeAsyncWork()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            throw new WebException("This is fake");
            return 1; // Unreachable!!
        }
```

Client Code:

```
var retryStrategy = new Incremental(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<SimpleHandlerStartegy>(retryStrategy);

retryPolicy.Retrying += (sender, retryArgs) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Retrying {0}, Delay{1}, Last Exception: {2}", retryArgs.CurrentRetryCount, retryArgs.Delay, retryArgs.LastException);
            };

// In real world, await this to get the return value
retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => SomeAsyncWorkThatThrows());
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, exceptions that are raised within an asynchronous code block are delivered back to the main thread within an aggregate exception. I suppose this is because raising an exception doesn't necessarily cause execution to be returned to the main thread and therefore we could have more than one exception returned.